# AG-GRID Angular - How to redraw one cellRender after change value on another cellRenderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have one grid with two CellRenderers.
The first one is a select that you choose a number, the second is a multiple selection.
I need to delete all the values in the second renderer after i change a number on the first one.

I have this code after choosing a new number:

```
 onChangeClick(e: any) {
this.params.data.renderOne = e.value;

if (e.value) {
  var itemsToUpdate = [];

  let currentIndex = this.params.rowIndex;
  var rowNode = this.params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(currentIndex);

  var data = rowNode.data;

  data.renderTwo = [];

  itemsToUpdate.push(data);

  this.params.api.applyTransactionAsync({ update: itemsToUpdate });
  this.params.api.refreshCells({ columns: ['renderTwo'] });
}
```

}

Changing the number, I see that the array turns empty but the multiple values that i choose before still appears after refreshCells().

How can i redraw only the 'renderTwo' renderer to empty the cell.
I have try api.redrawRows() but eliminates all the data from the line instead reset the renderTwo?

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5rkuf?file=src/app/render-one/render-one.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the interface for Redraw Rows:

```
interface RedrawRowsParams {
    rowNodes?: RowNode[]; // the row nodes to redraw
}
```

You can only redraw entire row nodes, so if you want to refresh the values inside your renderer, I'd recommend implementing the refresh method inside the second renderer:

```
  refresh(params: ICellEditorParams) {
    // set value into cell again
    this.params = params;
    this.renderTwoList = params.data.renderTwo;
    return true;
  }
```

Documentation:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-cell-renderer/#grid-vs-component-refresh-1
- https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-cell-renderer/#simple-cell-renderer
- https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/view-refresh/#redraw-rows

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rewniw?file=src%2Fapp%2Frender-two%2Frender-two.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is a way, but i need do set the values again to open the options. When refresh the list turns empty. How can I reset and then set the clean values again?

Comment: I found the solution. In the code you provide, what i need to do is return false instead true. Thank you a lot.